Using reveal.js within Quarto in R-Studio to publish to a nested folder?
I am building a series of presentations in reveal.js in Quarto for my teaching, and wish to "publish" to a folder within the main folder for the purposes of upload to a learning management system.  The reason is to separate the visualisation code and markup code from the html to automate an upload
The default structure appears to generate a file structure of:
main
|-presentation1_files
|-presentation1.qmd
|-presentation1.html
|-presentation2_files
|-presentation2.qmd
|-presentation2.html
|-visualisation_code

I'd like to output as:
main
|-html
   |-presentation1
      |-presentation1_files
      |-presentation1.html
   |-presentation2
      |-presentation2_files
      |-presentation2.html
|-presentation1.qmd
|-presentation2.qmd
|-visualisation_code

In a Quarto book, I can set the yaml file to do this through the use of
project:
  type: book
  output-dir: book_html

which does exactly what i'm after for the "book" (teaching notes)
Is there an output-dir: html/presentation1 type syntax I can use within the reveal.js markup which will put things in the right place as a self-contained HTML?
I can't see that this has a way to do this for the presentation (there doesn't seem to be a default Quarto "project: type:" yaml for presentations.  Have I missed something fundamental?
Thank you

In the YAML header of "presentation1.qmd" Tried using a YAML inclusion of
project:
  type: presentation
  output-dir: html

No errors, but no change.
Also tried
format: 
  revealjs:
    output-dir: html

Again, no errors, but no change.
Also sifted through the 18 pages of SO/SE results from a "quarto" "reveal.js" search, but noone appears to have asked this - but no definite statements that this desired result isn't possible either!
